# xcode 8: Change interface builder canvas

Tags: xcode8

I opened one of my old xib files, and then IB asked me to choose a device type. I then choose iPhone.

But, I do not see any iPad in the new preview.
[image]
How can I change the device canvas type?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managede to get iPads by setting "use trait variations" in "File Inspector".

Answer (score 2):

I would check Deployment info and you might just have Iphone checked instead of both.  If it is only set to iphone than you will not get ipad options.  Select both and now you will see the options for ipad.